# Handling errors when combining multiple WS calls into one result

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm learning scala, play, and web services all at once so bear with me. I've set up a little aggregator service that combines a weather web service and google's geocode and places web services. I've got something working but I'm a little confused on the proper way to handle errors. (I posted the code at the end of the post)

So the places api uses lat/long and so I use the geocode api to get lat/long from the zip code. When processing the response from the call to the geocode api I end up with an `(Option[String], Option[String])` (held in the `maybeLoc` val). Inside the match statement that checks `maybeLoc`, if it ends up being `(None, None)`, I return `Promise()` because I need to return a `Promise` from the flatmap call.

I have two questions about this:

1.) What is the right way to handle the case of not being able to do any further processing while inside one of these flatMap or map calls? It requires me to return a promise, but making an empty `Promise` that will just time out when I go to redeem it seems like a really bad idea.

2.) Am I right in assuming that the call to `Promise()` makes an empty promise object that will always time out when trying to redeem it? I couldn't really tell from the scaladoc and couldn't find anything about it from google.

I hope my questions make sense to you and are clear enough. Here is the code:

```
def bothAsJson(zipcode:String) = Action {
    val promiseOfLoc = Geocode.buildUrlFor(zipcode).get()
    val promiseOfWeather = Weather.buildUrlFor(zipcode, "json").get()

    val result = promiseOfLoc.flatMap { locResp => 
        val maybeLoc = Geocode.extractLocation(locResp.body.toString())
        maybeLoc match {
            case (Some(lat), Some(lng)) => {
                val promiseOfPlaces = Places.buildUrlFor(lat,lng).get()
                promiseOfPlaces.flatMap { placesResp =>
                    promiseOfWeather.map { weatherResp =>
                        (weatherResp.body.toString(), placesResp.body.toString())
                    }
                }
            }
            case _ => Promise()
        }
    }

    Async {
        result.orTimeout("Timeout!", 2000).map {response =>
            response.fold(
                result => Ok("Got:\n\nweather:\n" + result._1 + "\n\nplaces:\n" + result._2),
                timeout => InternalServerError(timeout)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get (None, None) you shouldn't be looking to timeout, but return another error message I believe. I've provided an example below.

I think you need OptionT from from scalaz 7. I would write this as:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

def bothAsJson(zipcode:String) = Action {
    val promiseOfLoc = Geocode.buildUrlFor(zipcode).get.map { Option(_.body.toString()) }
    val promiseOfWeather = Weather.buildUrlFor(zipcode, "json").get
       .map{ lockResp => 
           val (lat,lng) = Geocode.extractLocation(locResp.body.toString())
           (lat |@| lng).tupled
       }
    def buildPlaces(lat: String, lng: String) = Places.buildUrlFor(lat,lng).get
       .map { Option(_.body.toString) }

    val result = (for {
       (lat, lng) <- OptionT(promiseOfLoc)
       places     <- OptionT(Places.buildUrlFor(lat,lng).get())
       weather    <- OptionT(promiseOfWeather)
    } yield (places, weather)).run

    Async {
        result.orTimeout("Timeout!", 2000).map {response =>
            response.fold(
                result => {
                  result.map(
                   some => Ok("Got:\n\nweather:\n" + some._1 + "\n\nplaces:\n" + some._2)
                  ).getOrElse(BadRequest("lat/lng failed probably?"))
                },
                timeout => InternalServerError(timeout)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

With `OptionT` we can flatMap as if it was an `Option`, gaining the ability not to process anything if we get a None. At the end we are left with a `Promise[Option[T]]` which is very nice for this. Another way good way to handle errors is to use Either/EtherT with the same method.

`|@|` is an Applicative Builder. It takes 2 Options, and returning an `Option((Int, Int))` if both sides are `Some`. If one side or both sides are `None`, it returns a `None`.

Note for this to work you will need a scalaz `Monad[Promise]` instance

```
implicit val PromiseInstance = new Monad[Promise] {
  // override def map[A,B](fa: Promise[A])(f: A => B) = fa.map(f)
  def point[A](a: => A) = Promise.pure(a)
  def bind[A,B](fa: Promise[A])(f: A => Promise[B]) = fa.flatMap(f)
}
```

Also please note that I have written all this code in the SO editor, There could be braces missing. But all the code should be more or less right, I tested parts of it in the repl.

Please feel free to ask for help on #scalaz on freenode irc, or on the scalaz google groups.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I definitely do not want to time out just because an error happened in one of the calls -> but map was requiring  me to return a `Promise` no matter what. Looking at your example it is now very clear I should have it returning a `Promise[Either/Option]` instead of `Promise[String]`. Thanks again
*edit* err, I meant flatMap

Comment: flatMap is A => Promise[B], map is A => B. So you don't need to return a Promise at all with just map.

Comment: btw OptionT(Places.buildUrlFor(lat,lng).get()) should be OptionT(buildPlaces(lat,lng))